# Asp.Net Mvc Routing Issue with Default Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.Net Mvc website that has a listing controller. The route looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Pretty standard. Now I have a number of controller actions in my listing controller. I would like to be able to either go to /listing/84 and have it go to the Index action or to /listing/create, /listing/edit, /listing/favorite, or /listing/others and have it go to the the corresponding actions. For most of my routes this is already the case. This is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(long? id)
{
    // my code that never gets hit
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited the question to inform everyone that I have multiple actions in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a specific route for this and a constraint for the id:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ActionLess",
    "{controller}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" },
    new string[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much. Elegant solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two new route for it

For lisitng/Create for navigating Create Action

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "listingCreate", // Route name
     "listing/Create", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "listing", action = "Create" } 
);
```

For Index Action when passing Id

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "lisingid", // Route name
     "listing/{Id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "listing", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

I hope, It will help you.

Comment: One way to do it. I don't think it is a bad solution, but if I have 20 different actions then I will have to make 20 different methods.